# Changes to HTML template not reflected in Django after several steps taken

Tags: python, django

I have made major revisions to an HTML template on my dev Django server, but those changes are not reflected.

Here are troubleshooting steps I've tried:

1. Clear the browser cache
2. Close and reopen the browser after clearing all history
3. Try a different browser
4. Restart the server (`runserver`)
5. `python manage.py collectstatic --noinput --clear`
6. Check urls.py and settings.py to make sure everything is as it should be
7. Make sure you're editing the correct template
8. Restarted *the entire VPS server* (not just the webserver) and started up the web server again

Here's [the template](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/e3e13075790f6a3215a873a9394c84ac).

Here's [the view](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/2530cb1f34f37749fb426965994ab46d).

Comment: please add your urls, views and the template

Comment: @FazilZaid I added them.

Comment: What is the server?

Comment: @MattCremeens Oracle Linux (which is basically RHEL)

Comment: Do you run apache or nginx?

Comment: @MattCremeens In production I use Apache but this is just dev so I'm using `manage.py runserver`

Comment: Do you use a virtual environment? Sometimes I forget to activate it and then my work doesn't get updated.

Comment: @MattCremeens I do, yes (a Python 2.7 and Django 1.9x virtual environment). I had it activated, but I didn't realize that the virtual environment came into play here. Is there something within that folder I should examine?

Comment: When you run `collectstatic` make sure you are in your virtual environment and especially when you do any database migrations. In fact, to be safe, activating it would be the first thing I did when making changes.

Comment: Tried the django debug toolbar to make sure the template really is what you think it is? https://github.com/jazzband/django-debug-toolbar